# How return column from my DB using Java Spring JPQL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a very basic task. I want to return just one column from my table in my DB. Literally, I want the text from my `category_name`.  This is my JPQL cod:|

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "SELECT category_name FROM Category  WHERE id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
    String findName(@Param("id") long id);
```

And I have this error:

```
Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error apparently states, you should use `@Modifying` annotation when you are actually updating/deleting the row. Since you are fetching data from already stored database, you can simply remove this annotation.
You should also remove `@Transactional` annotation.
https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional is an interesting article to know about how transactional annotation works and when it should be used.